# Highlight and immediately speak selected text in one click - Text To Speech on Mac

Tags: macos, automator, shortcut, voice-dictation, text-to-speech

I am a very heavy text to speech user on the Mac. 
Every time I use text to speech I have to triple click the paragraph to select it, and then hit option escape to activate text to speech. I wish that instead I could just option click a paragraph and it would immediately start speaking. I imagine this could be achieved using Automator or a similar tool combined with shortcuts? Does anybody know how to make this happen?

Action I wish existed for text to speech:
Option + click = highlight the entire paragraph and immediately begin reading =  triple click + (option + Escape)

Comment: Using something like [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) you should be able to simulate the triple click and send the Option+Escape shortcut to trigger text to speech.

Comment: Additional needed commands: 
1. Highlight and begin reading all text in document downstream of click:
Command + Option + Click = command + shift + down arrow + (option + Escape) 
2. Command + Shift + S = Stop text to speech midway, when clicked again start 2 seconds earlier from where the voice stopped speaking.

Comment: @tubedogg thanks for the suggestion. I tried Karabiner, it looks very promising but I have yet to get it to work:

Here is my current XML attempt which does not work:
   `<item>
        <name>Click Speak</name>
        <identifier>private.option_click_to_speak</identifier>
        <name>Option+LeftClick to Option+RightClick</name>
        <autogen>
            __KeyToKey__
            PointingButton::LEFT, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_OPTION,
            PointingButton::MULTICLICK
            KeyCode::OPTION, ESCAPE
        </autogen>
    </item>`

Comment: I'll take a look at it later, but right off the bat, you need to change `OPTION` near the end to `ModifierFlag::OPTION_L`.

Comment: wow that was a fast responce! Will do now

Comment: Changed the option. The main issue I'm facing at the moment is the lack of the ability to do triple click and the lack of an ability to chain multiple commands.

Comment: Check the documentation for @begin and @end for chaining commands. Also check out the [samples](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner/blob/master/src/core/server/Resources/include/checkbox/samples.xml) and search that page for "double" - double (or triple) clicking is simply a matter of putting in multiple clicks, e.g. `<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::S, PointingButton::LEFT, PointingButton::LEFT, PointingButton::LEFT</autogen>`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an item that you can put in your Karabiner private.xml file to make <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Escape</kbd> highlight the current paragraph (under your mouse cursor) and being reading it.

I also implemented the command for stopping it as you requested (<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>) though I don't believe there's a way to go back two seconds and start reading again.

```
<item>
    <identifier>private.tripleclick</identifier>
    <name>Option-Escape to Triple-Click and Text-to-Speech</name>
    <autogen>
        __KeyToKey__
        KeyCode::ESCAPE, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L,

        @begin
        PointingButton::LEFT, PointingButton::LEFT, PointingButton::LEFT,
        KeyCode::ESCAPE, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L
        @end
    </autogen>
</item>
<item>
    <identifier>private.stoptts</identifier>
    <name>Command-Shift-S stops Text-to-Speech</name>
    <autogen>
        __KeyToKey__
        KeyCode::S, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L,
        KeyCode::ESCAPE, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L
    </autogen>
</item>
```

Comment: Thank you @tubedogg! I implemented this but it does not seem to work for me. When I hit option escape in Notes now for example, it highlights the entire document and starts reading it. However, for a computer where text to speech is enabled with the option escape shortcut. This is standard. When trying this on, when trying it in chrome on medium for example this does not seem to work for me. I tried tinkering with it but did not get it to work. What application did you test this with? Maybe I'm setting something up wrong with Karabiner. Thank you so so much for the help. I really appreciate it

Comment: Just to make sure, did you use the Reload XML button in Karabiner and then enable these two items in Karabiner's preferences? Otherwise, the normal Option-Escape command will happen instead. I tested this on Chrome (actually tested it again just now) and it seems to be working fine for me. Also, make sure you have `<?xml version="1.0"?>` on the first line of your private.xml file, `<root>` on the second, and `</root>` on the last line.